Message attribute names starting with 'AWS.' or 'Amazon.' are reserved for use by Amazon. - Nodejs
I'm integrating AWS SNS to send messages to Indian mobile numbers, having already registered my SenderID with DLT and obtained approval from AWS. However, when attempting to include the EntityID and TemplateID in my code as instructed by AWS, I'm encountering an error stating 'Message attribute names starting with 'AWS.' or 'Amazon.' are reserved for use by Amazon.' Where exactly should I include these IDs in my AWS SNS code to resolve this issue?
here is a code with nodejs
const sendSnsMessage = async (message, phone) => {
  try {
    let params = {
      Message: message,
      PhoneNumber: phone,
      MessageAttributes: {
        "AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType": {
          DataType: "String",
          StringValue: "Transactional",
        },
        "AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID": {
          DataType: "String",
          StringValue: <my-sender-id>,
        },
        "AWS.SNS.SMS.EntityID": {
          DataType: "String",
          StringValue: <entity-id>,
        },
        "AWS.SNS.SMS.TemplateID": {
          DataType: "String",
          StringValue: <template-id>,
        },
      },
    };

    let publishCmd = new PublishCommand(params);
    let sentMsg = await SNS.send(publishCmd);
    return sentMsg;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("errrr",error.message);
  }
};

Edit: Removed AWS prefix from EntityID and TemplateID, resolving reserved attribute error, but now receiving SMS with short code; how to use registered SenderID with AWS SNS for Indian mobile numbers?
SenderID accepted mail from AWS

But still receiving message with random short numbers. Why?

Removed AWS prefix from EntityID and TemplateID, resolving reserved attribute error.
But, here is code winch actually works me.
  MessageAttributes: {
        "AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID": {
          DataType: "String",
          StringValue: <Sender-Id>,
        },
        "AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType": {
          DataType: "String",
          StringValue: "Transactional",
        },
        "AWS.MM.SMS.EntityId": {
          DataType: "String",
          StringValue: <entityId>,
        },
        "AWS.MM.SMS.TemplateId": {
          DataType: "String",
          StringValue: <templateId>,
        },
      },

If still received messages with random short numbers instead of Sender ID. So the fix is

Confirm that your Sender ID was successfully registered with AWS and TRAI
Includes a policy to allow it to be used by the SNS service

To do so: On the AWS End User Messaging Console, navigate to "Sender IDs". Click on Sender ID, where you will be able to see the resource policy. Click on 'Edit' and add the following sample policy (or ensure similar permissions are already present);
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sms-voice:SendTextMessage",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sms-voice:ap-south-1:211125419280:sender-id/<Sender-Id>/IN",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:SourceAccount": "211125419280"
            }
        }
    }]
}

